# How to emit the server path to the current file using Sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I have some components that I've broken into multiple smaller files. The main file includes them using `data-sly-include` attributes.

I'd like to generate HTML comments containing the current filename in both the main file and the included files, so that when I view the rendered output I can easily tell which file generated the output. Something like:

```
... some HTML from the template or other components...
<!-- begin /path/to/main/file.html -->
<div>
    This is from the main file
    <!-- begin  /path/to/main/includes/first.html -->
    <p>This is fromt the first include</p>
    <!-- end /path/to/main/includes/first.html -->
    <!-- begin  /path/to/main/includes/second.html -->
    <p>This is fromt the second include</p>
    <!-- end /path/to/main/includes/second.html -->
    now we're back in the main file
<!-- end /path/to/main/file.html -->
```

I can see how to get the path to the current page, but that's the resource that contains my component; I want the paths to the files that make up the components. Any way to do this in Sightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sightly script engine has the current file as a binding variable with sling, so the following should work-

```
sling.getScript().getScriptResource().getPath()
```

you will have to put this in a js file and call it from all your sightly scripts.

Comment: Thanks! That's a rather bare-bones answer, but it gave me enough to go on. I put that code into a .js file along with my component: `use( function() {
    return { "path" : sling.getScript().getScriptResource().getPath() };
});`

Then in my component markup, I added
`<sly data-sly-use.currentFile="../component-path.js"><!--  begin: ${currentFile.path} --></sly>` and I now see the path to the fragment in a comment in the rendered HTML. Warning: the markup needs access to the JS script -- if it's not in the same directory, you need to locate it as appropriate with `../`, `/etc/...` etc.